# Facebook and SSL partially encrypted

Tags: facebook, ssl

I got problem when loading Facebook Javascript SDK, it will causing my SSL connection partially encrypted. I try load not using the asychronous one but the result same. Do you have solution for this problem guys?

Thanks
@andriansandi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the code facebook gives to implement the JS SDK uses a protocol relative URL ... The URL of the JS file is `//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js`.
By not specifying http/https the browser will automatically use whichever protocol the page was requested with.
  Try substituting that with `https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js`.  This will force facebook to load the SDK over https.

Comment: Hi Lix, i still got same problem.

Comment: Are you requesting and displaying any photo's/profile pictures in your app?

Comment: No, i just want the library loaded on my app

Comment: My buddy chrome said : "The page at https://jakartainteractivehub.com/blackberry/bellagio/ ran insecure content from http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8.1/jquery.validate.min.js." - You are referencing resources over http.

Comment: Wow that's nice i will remove it. Thanks buddy